# How can I make the D3 Collide force apply only on X

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to use the Collide force in D3 to prevent overlaps between nodes in a force layout, but my y-axis is time-based. I would like to only use the force on the nodes' x positions.

I have tried to combine the collide force with a forceY but if I increase the collide radius I can see that nodes get pushed off frame so the Y position is not preserved.

```
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data.nodes)
    .force('links', d3.forceLink(data.links))
    .force('x', d3.forceX(width/2))      
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(5))
    .force('y', d3.forceY( function(d) { 
      var date = moment(d.properties.date, "YYYY-MM-DD");
      var timepos = y_timescale(date)
      return timepos; }));
```

My hunch is that I could modify the [source](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/src/collide.js) for `forceCollide()` and remove y but I am  just using D3 with `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>` and I'm not sure how to start making a custom version of the force.

Edit: I have added more context in response to the answer below:
- full code sample [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1862402)
- screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mfus5mkjok3j3e/Screenshot%20from%202019-05-31%2014-23-04.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite enough code in the question to guarantee this is what you need, but making some assumptions:

Often when using a force layout you would allow the forces to calculate the positions and then reposition the node to a given [x,y] co-ordinate on tick e.g.

```
function ticked() {
    nodeSelection.attr('cx', d => d.x).attr('cy', d => d.y);
}
```

Since you don't want the forces to affect the y co-ordinate just remove it from here i.e.

```
nodeSelection.attr('cx', d => d.x);
```

And set the y position on, say, enter:

```
nodeSelection = nodeSelection
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', 2)
    .attr('cy', d => { 
      // Set y position based on scale here
    })
    .merge(nodeSelection);
```

Comment: Hi @Tom many thanks for your reply. 
I tried this since asking the question. It helps but the collide force doesn' t work as well as it is still using a d.y position which isn't the correct one. This still results in overlaps, as you can see in [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mfus5mkjok3j3e/Screenshot%20from%202019-05-31%2014-23-04.png?dl=0).

Is there a way to have the collide force not touch the y position but still still take it into account? I have been trying to modify the function but I can't make sense of it: https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/src/collide.js

Comment: in the screenshot the radii of the node and the collide force are both set to the same value (40)